# Unwrapping the Haskell State Monad

Tags: haskell

In the process of writing an assignment for university I am having the ever-joyous fun of learning new Haskell monads. Yay!!!

I have a function that typechecks just fine:

```
compile :: Prog -> State VarsState String
compile prog@(Prog functions) = do
    s1 <- sequence (map (translate_func 0) [get_function prog name | name <- [func_name func | func <- functions]])
    return $ trace ("here's the program: \n" ++ show prog) $ concat $ s1
```

but when this other function:

```
maybe_compile_prog ::
    MaybeOK Prog -> String -> IO ()
maybe_compile_prog (Error msg) _ = do
    putStrLn ("error: " ++ msg)
maybe_compile_prog (OK prog) modulename = do
    s1 <- compile prog
    writeFile (modulename ++ ".m") ((header modulename) ++ s1)
```

tries to call it, it blows up at the line

```
s1 <- compile prog
```

saying it couldn't match the expected type "IO t0" with actual type "State VarsState String".

I assume this is because maybe_compile_prog returns type IO () so it expects to only unwrap IO information? VarsState is a custom datatype I have made to use with the State monad/

However, if that is the problem and I assume it is, I don't know how to transmit this simple string to maybe_compile_prog. Really, that's all I want to do - give a string to maybe_compile_prog.

Perhaps there's some neat way to unwrap this state monad? Perhaps it's possible to rewrite "compile" so that it takes in some state monad information whilst it runs, but then just returns a string (not wrapped in any monad)?

Please let me know if I'm missing any information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`compile prog` is an action in the `State VarsState` monad, thus you cannot use it in an `IO`-do-block as such. In a do-block, all lines must use the same monad, in this case `IO`.

You need to "run" the `compile` action to obtain the result, with one of

```
runState :: State s a -> s -> (a,s)
evalState :: State s a -> s -> a
execState :: State s a -> s -> s
```

depending on whether you need

- both, result and final state
- only result
- only final state

In your case, you only want the result, so `evalState` it is.

For that you need to provide an initial state, it could look like

```
maybe_compile_prog (OK prog) modulename = do
    let s1 = evalState (compile prog) initialState
    writeFile (modulename ++ ".m") ((header modulename) ++ s1)
```

but then the provided initial state for the `compile` action would be the same for all `OK prog`s passed. If that is not the right thing, you could pass the initial state as a parameter too.

Comment: Perfect dude. Except for one small thing, it compiles with "let s1 = evalState (compile prog) initialState", not "let s1 = evalState $ compile prog initialState". One other questions - are there functions like this for other monads? i.e. functions that unwrap the monad and return you just the result?

Comment: @nebffa depends entirely on the monad in question, but yes, some of them do. It's not something you can do generically for all monads. One other example would be the dreaded `unsafePerformIO` for the `IO` monad, but you shouldn't use that.

Comment: Ah, yes, mixed up the parentheses (forgot the state first, and then forgot to exchange the `$` when adding it). Thanks for the heads-up. For many monads, there are corresponding functions, but not for all. `IO` is one where there is none such [well, there is one whose name begins with `unsafe` and it really really means it]. There are `runIdentity`, `runReader`, `runWriter`, `runCont`, ... Look at the docs for each monad whether there are such functions.